# Object spread operator syntax not working properly with computed property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

In simple component I have get filter props. I want to override object property dynamic computed property stored in variable. 
I want mutate state of the application.

```js
var props = {};

// data inside props.filter
    props.filter = {
        "employeeAttributes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "attributeName": "FIRST_NAME",
                "attributeType": "TEXT",
                "displayName": "First Name",
                "active": false,
                "attributeValue": ""
            },
        ],
        "companyAttributes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "attributeName": "EMPLOYEE_TYPE",
                "attributeType": "SELECT",
                "displayName": "Employee Type",
                "active": false,
                "attributeValue": ""
            },
        ]
    }

    // computed attribute
    let attr = 'companyAttributes';

    // new updatedCompanyAttribute
    const updatedCompanyAttribute = [{
            "id": 2,
            "attributeName": "OFFICE_LOCATION",
            "attributeType": "SELECT",
            "displayName": "Office Location",
            "active": false,
            "attributeValue": ""
        },
    ];

    // nextState
    const nextState = {...props.filter, [attr]: updatedCompanyAttribute };
    console.log(nextState)
```

Comment: What is not working properly? Your code is correct. Do you want to add everything in `updatedCompanyAttribute` to the existing `companyAttributes` array?

Comment: Your right ... checkout this link https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4196  I just want to use computed property with object spread operator.

Comment: If you want to add them to the array you have to write `const nextState = { ...props.filter, [attr]: [...props.filter[attr], ...updatedCompanyAttribute] };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Edit vq03pjk0y3]

Do you mean to add  to existing `companyAttributes` property ?

```
const updatedCompanyAttribute = {
        "id": 2,
        "attributeName": "OFFICE_LOCATION",
        "attributeType": "SELECT",
        "displayName": "Office Location",
        "active": false,
        "attributeValue": ""
    }

const nextState = {
   ...props.filter, 
   [attr]: [ ...props.filter[attr], updatedCompanyAttribute ] 
};
```

`...props.filter[attr]` will spread all the values of companyAttributes to prepopulate the new array with it, and then `updatedCompanyAttribute` will add the new value to it.

if you write :

```
const nextState = {
   ...props.filter, 
   [attr]: updatedCompanyAttribute
};
```

you are replacing the content of `companyAttributes` property with the value of `updatedCompanyAttribute`, without adding existing values already there

Comment: Thanks @Jayffe, I looking for the same. Can you explain syntax 
const nextState = {
   ...props.filter, 
   [attr]: [ ...props.filter[attr], updatedCompanyAttribute ] 
};

Or any link related for the same.

Comment: This is also working fine. https://jsbin.com/virofureke/edit?js,console

Comment: I've edited my answer to add some more explanations, hope it helps :)